# Is it possible to read content from a local text file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, text

I am creating a simple web page to show some content that is created dynamically on my computer and saved in a text file.  In looking around, the only way I see to read content from a text file using javascript is to use something that prompts the user for a file read on their system.  Something like:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```

Is there anyway around this?  Is there anyway that I can pass a filename in and read the contents?

Comment: is it possible for you to use any server side code, like php or asp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to read a file from the browser without user interaction. That would be a serious security issue. Imagine that any website could read whatever they wanted on your computer. That opens a huge door for abuse.

Comment: Well, if the user is prompted and he chooses himself that file, then it is possible.

Comment: @Cristy OP asked whether a means of reading a file without user interaction exists.

Comment: Thanks.  I will just use the prompt for file.